# Postback causes page to "flash" when MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have done quite a lot of research online and would have thought this would have been a fairly easy fix, but either I'm just not searching correctly or I'm missing the answer:
I have an aspx page and a little C# inside of that. I have a checkedchanged event on a switch to hide/show a textbox. When the event fires, the postback causes the page to go to the top. I tried MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback set to true, and while that does maintain the scroll position, the postback causes the page to "flash" and is very unpleasant.
How can I either hide this transition, or preferably, eliminate it.
Thanks for your consideration.

**As suggested by @dave_holden, I put it inside an UpdatePanel and that works.**
(At least until I remember why I didn't use one in the first place. :)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="blah" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Windows" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

protected void cbSignator_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbSignator.Checked)
    {
        tbSignator.Visible = true;
        lblSignator.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        tbSignator.Visible = false;
        lblSignator.Visible = false;
        tbSignator.Text = "";
    }
}

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Request Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <form id="Contract" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> 

    <section id="CustomerInfo">
        <div class="row" id="customerFields2">
            <div class="column">
                <label class="switch">
                    <span class="slider"></span>
                </label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSignatory" runat="server" CssClass="labels" Text="Will be signatory?" />
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSignator" runat="server" CssClass="labels" Visible="false" Text="Signator:" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbSignator" runat="server" class="textboxes" Visible="false" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Use Ajax to post maybe?

Comment: I ran into an issue with that last week, but may revisit...

Comment: UpdatePanel will get rid of this issue. It uses AJAX instead of a post back. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.8

Also, do not put C# code mixed in with presentation markup. Put it in the code-behind file where it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @dave_holden, I put it inside an UpdatePanel and that works. (At least until I remember why I didn't use one in the first place. :)